# Image pathname from mysql php doesn't display the image

Tags: php, image, pathname

So after I store a pathname of an image file in mysql php, I am having difficulty retrieving that image to display. In other words, when I do an "inspect element" the "src" value is set. However, the image doesnt display and all that is left is a square box on the page. I tried using a default profile picture that is already set for the user, just to check if its a php assigning value problem. But its not. I also checked the file contents physically and all the files are uploaded fine. The only problem is getting it to display.

Here's how I do it.

**Php for checking file upload**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"&&isset($_POST["savePersonalInfo"]))
{
 if(isset($_FILES["ppFile"]))
 {
  $name=$_FILES["ppFile"]["name"];
  $tempName=$_FILES["ppFile"]["tmp_name"];
  $size=$_FILES["ppFile"]["size"];
  $type=$_FILES["ppFile"]["type"];

   if(($type=="image/jpg"||$type=="image/jpeg"||$type=="image/pjpeg")&&( ($size>0&&$size<=4000000000))
    {

     $dir="C:/xampp/htdocs/hcUsers/".$_SESSION['pin']."/profilePictures";

     $realPath=$dir."/".$name;

     if(is_dir($dir))
     {
       move_uploaded_file($tempName,$realPath);

       $_SESSION["ppPath"]=$realPath;

       $fileQuery="UPDATE `current users` SET `ppPath`='$realPath' WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['pin']."' " ;

       checkConnect(mysql_query($fileQuery),"query of $fileQuery");

     }
     else
     {
       mkdir($dir,0777,true);

       move_uploaded_file($tempName, $realPath);

       $_SESSION["ppPath"]=$realPath;

       $fileQuery="UPDATE `current users` SET `ppPath`='$realPath' WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['pin']."' " ;

       checkConnect(mysql_query($fileQuery),"query of $fileQuery"); 
     }
  }

    else
 {
   print "Error".$_FILES["ppFile"]["error"];
 }
```

}

?>

**Php for retrieving the image pathname and displaying the image**

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    connectDatabase();
    $query="SELECT * FROM `current users` WHERE `email`='".$_SESSION['email']."' AND `      `password`='".$_SESSION['password']."' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    checkConnect($result,"query of $query");
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION["pin"]=$row["id"];

    $imgPath="http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/images/covers/avariel-no-end-in-sight(demo)-20110719103608.jpg";

  if($row["ppPath"]!="")
  {
   $imgPath=$row["ppPath"];
   $_SESSION["ppPath"]=$imgPath;
  }  
?>

 <p><img src="<?php echo $imgPath ?>" alt="" type="image/jpeg" class="profilePic" >
```

In the end the 'src' value is set but the image won't display.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of your code:

```
$dir="C:/xampp/htdocs/hcUsers/".$_SESSION['pin']."/profilePictures";

$realPath=$dir."/".$name;

if(is_dir($dir))
{
    move_uploaded_file($tempName,$realPath);

    $_SESSION["ppPath"]=$realPath;

    $fileQuery="UPDATE `current users` SET `ppPath`='$realPath' WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['pin']."' " ;
```

This way, when retreiving ppPath from the database and trying to display it in a browser, the `src` of the image will point to `C:/xampp/etc`. That won't work, since your visitors don't have access to that directory. Neither do you, from a browser's  perspective. Change it to a relative URL.

Furthermore I see a lot of duplicate code and you're abusing session variables, but that's offtopic.

Comment: Simply don't save the local part when uploading, just store the filename of the image.

Comment: You only need to store `"/hcUsers/" . $_SESSION['pin'] . "/profilePictures/" . $name`. From there it's relative to your document root.

Comment: abusing session variables? IS it a part of unobtrusive programming or is it harmful for my website?

Comment: What do you do with `$_SESSION["ppPath"]`? And why do you log in the user on every view? :)

Comment: I made the changes as you told me. But now, the image itself doesn't save on in the hcUsers. here's what I did ` `$dir="/hcUsers/".$_SESSION['pin']."/profilePictures";` `$realPath=$dir."/".$name;`

Comment: You have to save them using full path of course, but only use the relative path in the database.

Comment: and in the src? Should I use fullpath or relpath?